# Adding a GeoTiff created in QGIS to Map Box

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, mapbox

I have created a heat map in QGIS and have successfully exported it as a Geotif file. I exported the file as a Rendered Image to include my classifications and colors. However when I pull the data into Tile Mill or Map Box, all of the pixels with "No Data" get colored as white or black. I have tired setting the "No Data" to be 100% transparent in QGIS but this did not change anything. I want the white/black space to be excluded.

[image]

Comment: Is this what Turf is for? https://www.mapbox.com/blog/heatmaps-and-grids-with-turf/ (just in case you want to skip creating the raster...)

Comment: No but that is pretty cool!

Comment: Find TileMill docs on working with [rasters here](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/reprojecting-geotiff/), and on using the [CartoCSS raster-colorizer property here](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/discrete-raster-data/) and [here](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/colorizing-single-band-raster-data/).  I don't think the TileMill docs are linked from the MapBox home page anymore b/c they are trying to phase TileMill out in favor of MapBox Studio.  MB Studio doesn't have the same level of support for rasters, though.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work. I believe a combination of setting the transparency for NoData values and removing the map background color in Tile Mill solved my issue.